# Gulp 4 multiple async subtasks

Tags: javascript, gulp

how do I run multiple async subtasks in the Gulp task? In general, this task runs and starts copying the files but throws an error at the end.

- The following tasks did not complete: build, copy:default
- Did you forget to signal async completion?

```
gulp.task('copy:default', () => {

  const fonts = gulp.src(['src/fonts/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));
  const images = gulp.src(['src/images/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
  const scripts = gulp.src(['src/scripts/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));

  return ['fonts', 'images', 'scripts']

});
```

I'm using this like this:

```
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clean:dist', 'copy:default', 'sass'));
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd separate every `gulp.src` into a function which returns a `Promise` and then call all function in an array of promises. Then `Promise.all` with said array.

Comment: I did like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Loa6m4xh/ but still getting an error like previously.

Comment: You have several mistakes in your code. I made a working solution for you in a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```
gulp.task('copy:default', () => {
  const finalPromise = new Promise(finalResolve => {

    const fonts = new Promise(resolve => {
      gulp.src(['src/fonts/**/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
        .on('end', resolve);
    })

    const images = new Promise(resolve => {
      gulp.src(['src/images/**/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
        .on('end', resolve)
    })

    const scripts = new Promise(resolve => {
      gulp.src(['src/scripts/**/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
        .on('end', resolve);
    })

    Promise.all([fonts, images, scripts]).then(result => {
      finalResolve(result);
    });
  });

  return finalPromise;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This `return ['fonts', 'images', 'scripts']` just returns an array of strings which is not sufficient.

Look at [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) and https://mariusschulz.com/blog/merging-two-gulp-streams to actually return the streams.

```
const merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('copy:default', () => {

  const fonts = gulp.src(['src/fonts/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));
  const images = gulp.src(['src/images/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
  const scripts = gulp.src(['src/scripts/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));

  // return ['fonts', 'images', 'scripts']
  return merge(fonts, images, scripts);

});
```

or

```
gulp.task('copy:default', () => {

  return merge(
    gulp.src(['src/fonts/**/*'])
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts')),
    gulp.src(['src/images/**/*'])
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images')),
    gulp.src(['src/scripts/**/*'])
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
  ); 
});
```